# Vue v-data-table wrapper component issue with the same column value names

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

My v-data-table wrapper component:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="remappedItems"
    :page="state.currentPage"
    :items-per-page="state.pageSize"
    :height="state.tableHeight"
    :server-items-length="isServerSide ? totalItems : -1"
    v-bind="{ ...$props, ...$attrs }"
    :sort-by="sortOptions.sortBy"
    :sort-desc="sortOptions.sortDesc"
    must-sort
    hide-default-footer
    @click:row="$emit('click:row', $event)"
    @update:options="handleTableOptions"
  >
    <template v-for="header in headers" #[`item.${header.value}`]="{ item }">
      <div :key="header.value" :style="{ width: header.width }">
        <!-- RENDER custom slot -->
        <template v-if="header.type === 'slot'">
          <slot :name="header.value" :row="item" />
        </template>
        <!-- Normal rendering -->
        <template v-else>
          <div v-if="header.type === 'link'">
            <nuxt-link
              v-if="header.customProps"
              v-bind="header.customProps(item)"
            >
              {{ item[header.value] }}
            </nuxt-link>
          </div>

          <div v-else-if="header.type === 'date'">
            {{
              formatDateTime(item[header.value], {
                format: header.dateFormat,
              }) || item[header.value]
            }}
          </div>

          <div v-else-if="header.type === 'checkbox'">
            <v-checkbox
              :input-value="getCheckboxValue(item[header.value])"
              readonly
              v-bind="header.customProps"
            />
          </div>

          <div v-else-if="header.type === 'button'">
            <ConsBtn
              v-bind="header.customProps"
              @click="header.clickEvent ? header.clickEvent(item) : null"
            >
              {{ item[header.value] }}
            </ConsBtn>
          </div>

          <!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-v-html -->
          <div v-else-if="header.isHtml" v-html="item[header.value]" />

          <div v-else>
            {{ item[header.key || header.value] }}
          </div>
        </template>
      </div>
    </template>

    <template v-if="!props.hideFooter" #footer>
      <v-row ref="footer" align="center" class="grey--text text--darken-2">
        <v-col v-if="totalItems > state.pageSize" cols="auto">
          <v-pagination
            v-model="state.currentPage"
            :length="pageCount"
            :total-visible="totalVisiblePages"
          />
        </v-col>
        <v-col class="d-flex align-center">
          <div v-if="totalItems > state.pageSize">
            Записи {{ range }} из {{ totalItems }}
          </div>
          <div v-else>Записей {{ totalItems }}</div>

          <div class="ml-auto d-flex align-center sizer">
            <span class="mr-3">Показывать по</span>
            <v-select
              v-model="state.pageSize"
              :items="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 300]"
              solo
              dense
              hide-details
            />
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, computed, onMounted, reactive } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import { useDate } from '@web-aml-v2/shared/composables'
import { get } from 'lodash'

type ColumnType = 'link' | 'date' | 'checkbox' | 'button' | 'slot'

interface Props {
  headers?: Array<{
    key: string
    text: string
    value: string
    type: ColumnType
    dateFormat: string
    customProps?: (item: Record<string, unknown>) => Record<string, unknown>
    clickEvent?: (item: Record<string, unknown>) => void
    formatter?: (value: unknown) => unknown
    isHtml?: boolean
    width?: string
  }>
  items?: Array<Record<string, unknown>>
  totalItems?: number
  totalVisiblePages?: number
  defaultPageSize?: number
  isServerSide?: boolean
  hideFooter?: boolean
  sort?: string | null
  value?: any[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  headers: () => [],
  items: () => [],
  totalItems: 0,
  totalVisiblePages: 10,
  defaultPageSize: 10,
  isServerSide: true,
  hideFooter: false,
  sort: null,
  value: () => [],
})

const { formatDateTime } = useDate()

const emit = defineEmits(['update:options', 'input'])

interface State {
  currentPage: number
  pageSize: number
  previousPageSize: number
  currentSort: string | null
  tableHeight: string
}

const defaultState = {
  currentPage: 1,
  pageSize: props.defaultPageSize,
  previousPageSize: props.defaultPageSize,
  currentSort: null,
  tableHeight: 'auto',
}

const state = reactive<State>({ ...defaultState })
const isMounted = ref(false)

const remappedItems = computed(() => {
  function getItemValue(
    value: unknown,
    formatter?: (value: unknown) => unknown
  ) {
    if (formatter) {
      return formatter(value)
    }
    return value === null || value === undefined || value === '' ? '—' : value
  }

  return props.items?.map((item) => {
    const newItem: Record<string, unknown> = { ...item }

    // remove useless links array
    if ('links' in newItem) {
      delete newItem.links
    }

    props.headers?.forEach((header) => {
      const key = header.key || header.value
      newItem[key] = getItemValue(get(item, header.value), header.formatter)
      header.value = key
    })
    return newItem
  })
})

function getCheckboxValue(value: unknown) {
  return Boolean(value) && value !== '—'
}

const range = computed(() => {
  const start = (state.currentPage - 1) * state.pageSize
  let end = start + state.pageSize
  if (end > props.totalItems) {
    end = props.totalItems
  }
  return `${start + 1} - ${end}`
})

const pageCount = computed(() => {
  return Math.ceil(props.totalItems / state.pageSize)
})

const selected = computed({
  get() {
    return props.value || []
  },
  set(val) {
    emit('input', val)
  },
})

/**
 * Sorting logic
 */
const sortOptions = computed(() => {
  const [sortBy = '', sortDesc = 'asc'] = props.sort
    ? props.sort.split(',')
    : []
  return {
    sortBy,
    sortDesc: sortDesc === 'desc',
  }
})

function handleTableOptions(options: {
  page: number
  itemsPerPage: number
  sortBy: string[]
  sortDesc: boolean[]
}) {
  if (!isMounted.value) {
    return
  }

  const { sortBy, sortDesc } = options

  // Handle page reset when itemsPerPage changes
  if (state.pageSize !== state.previousPageSize) {
    state.currentPage = 1
    state.previousPageSize = state.pageSize
  }

  // Handle sort changes
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const sortOrder = sortDesc[0] ? 'desc' : 'asc'
    const sortString = `${sortBy[0]},${sortOrder}`
    if (state.currentSort !== sortString) {
      state.currentSort = sortString
    }
  }

  emit('update:options', {
    page: state.currentPage - 1,
    size: state.pageSize,
    sort: state.currentSort,
  })
}

onMounted(() => {
  isMounted.value = true
})

function resetState() {
  Object.assign(state, defaultState)
}

defineExpose({
  resetState,
})
</script>
</style>
```

Using this table component:

```
const headers = computed(() => {
  return [
          {
        text: 'Refuse1',
        value: 'refuseCodeReason',
      },
      {
        text: 'Refuse2',
        value: 'refuseCodeReason',
        key: 'refuseCodeReasonFormatted',
        formatter: (value: string) => {
          return (
            dictStore.formattedDictionaries[271]?.find(
              (item) => item.code === value
            )?.name || '—'
          )
        },
      }
  ]
})
<CustomTable :headers="headers" />
```

`dictStore.formattedDictionaries[271]` is just a computed method with values stored in dictionary, not fetched from API, it's static data. As you can see, i have 2 columns in the table, but latest column has `formatter` function applied, thus it is overriding the previous column with it's formatted value.
Is there a way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

As both the columns in `v-data-table` have the same value for `value` property, It means they bound to the same variable in the data source.

Hence, when you apply `formatter` on the latest column configuration. It will update both the columns as they are linked to the same underlying data as formatters in Vuetify operate on the value of bound property and as yours both columns bound to same property variable, any changes in one value will reflect in both the columns value.

To get rid from this issue, You have to ensure that both columns `value` property is bound to separate variable in a data source.

Example **:**

```
const headers = computed(() => {
  return [
          {
        text: 'Refuse1',
        value: 'refuseCodeReason',
      },
      {
        text: 'Refuse2',
        value: 'refuseCodeReason1', // You have to assign a separate variable here
        key: 'refuseCodeReasonFormatted',
        formatter: (value: string) => {
          return (
            dictStore.formattedDictionaries[271]?.find(
              (item) => item.code === value
            )?.name || '—'
          )
        },
      }
  ]
})
```